# MySQL - Select the most recent record by date from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL db and I have two tables, the first one is like this:

```
Product
GTIN | Name | Dosage | Quantity
111    AAA     10         500
222    BBB     35         199
333    CCC     15         33
```

and the second table,

```
Product_price
ID | GTIN | product_price | product_date
1    111      15             2020-11-23 10:30:00
1    111      17             2021-07-15 08:05:17
1    222      35             2019-01-03 00:00:00
1    111      19             2022-01-09 11:35:00
1    333      65             2011-11-11 00:00:00
1    222      45             2021-11-23 00:00:00
```

Can someone help me to get the desired result?
I want to get the latest price for each product based on gtin. The result would look like this,

```
Result
GTIN | Name | Dosage | Quantity | Price
111    AAA     10         500      19
222    BBB     35         199      45
333    CCC     15         33       65
```

Comment: Please show us your best attempt.

Comment: which db version are you use?

Comment: >>which db version are you use?
MySQL 8.0

Comment: @astentx
I had a look at it. In my case I am using inner join between two tables and I was struggling

Comment: @astentx Those links which you added are not similar to my question an anway. Firstly I am using two tables which need inner join and secondly I have to compare dates!!

Comment: @ZAJ Two tables can be represented as one via join, that's why it doesn't matter. And the datatype of *last record* doesn't matter also, because anything that can have an order (i.e. that has `>=` comparison defined for the datatype) is processed in the same way. See [Total order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.GTIN, p.Name, p.Dosage, P.Quantity, pp.product_price
FROM Product p INNER JOIN
     Product_price pp
     ON p.GTIN = pp.GTIN
WHERE pp.date = (SELECT MAX(p2.date)
                FROM Product_price p2
                WHERE p2.GTIN = pp.GTIN
               );
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your query worked as expected!!. Thanks a lot. If I want to filter based on GTIN, how will the query look it.

Comment: Just to confirm, I just added gtin to the where clause like so,

`SELECT p.GTIN, pp.price_date, pp.price 
FROM Product p INNER JOIN
     product_price pp
ON p.GTIN = pp.GTIN
WHERE pp.price_date = (SELECT MAX(p2.price_date)
                FROM Product_price p2
                WHERE p2.GTIN = pp.GTIN
               ) and p.gtin = 111;`

Comment: SELECT p.GTIN, p.Name, p.Dosage, P.Quantity, pp.product_price
FROM Product p INNER JOIN
     Product_price pp
     ON p.GTIN = pp.GTIN
WHERE pp.date = (SELECT MAX(p2.date)
                FROM Product_price p2
                WHERE p2.GTIN = pp.GTIN
               ) and p.GTIN=111;

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution, thanks. How do I display the max date in the result set too?

Comment: SELECT p.GTIN, p.Name, p.Dosage, p.Quantity, pp.product_price, pp.product_date
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Product_price pp ON p.GTIN = pp.GTIN
WHERE pp.product_date = (
    SELECT MAX(p2.product_date)
    FROM Product_price p2
    WHERE p2.GTIN = pp.GTIN
);


@Rotimi